# How do I make "cp" in OS X not delete files?

Tags: macos, cp

Here's the best way to describe this:

```
dirA
   dir1
      file1.txt
      file3.txt
dirB
   dir1
      file1.txt
      file2.txt
```

I want to copy the contents of dirB into dirA.  `cp -R dirB/* dirA` would delete `dir1` and copy the files, resulting in:

```
dirA
   dir1
      file1.txt
      file2.txt
```

But I want to merge them (like it would on Windows) and end up with:

```
dirA
   dir1
      file1.txt
      file2.txt
      file3.txt
```

Suggestions?  I've tried `ditto`, but that seems to ignore the recursive part and just dump all the files in the top-level folder.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html is the man page for cp.

Comment: How does Windows merge those two files with the name `file1.txt`?

Comment: I just tested cp -R on Snow Leopard and it will do just what you want. It will overwrite the files in dirA that have the same name but it won't delete any files.

Comment: thanks Raynet, I didn't think I was getting that result but I'll check again.  

the issue here involves subversion.  I need to dump a bunch of folders/files into a version-controlled folder, but it needs to leave all existing files there so it doesn't clobber the .svn files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use cp. Use [rsync](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/rsync/).

([Apple dev link](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rsync.1.html).)

Answer (score 3):

[cp](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html) does **not** delete files.

Comment: it does in that it overwrites dirA/dir1 with dirB/dir1, rather than just copying the files in that folder.  so the behavior is delete-then-copy (when compared with with the Windows way, which is to merge the folders.)

Comment: cp does overwrite files. From a user point of view, this is the same as deleting: an overwritten file is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-i` option to cp

```
     -i    Cause cp to write a prompt to the standard error output before
           copying a file that would overwrite an existing file.  If the
           response from the standard input begins with the character `y'
           or `Y', the file copy is attempted.  (The -i option overrides
           any previous -n option.)
```

Comment: This will get you part way there -- it will at least stop unintentionally slamming of files. `rsync` is a better file sync problem.

Comment: I'll check rsync.  the issue with -i (thanks MarkM, I did check the man page first :/) is that I'm dealing with big directory trees and can't confirm every single overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

There's gotta be an elegant way, but as a quick hack: remove write permission from the files in dir1, then do a cp -r.

Comment: I don't know whether to upvote for simplicity and hackiness or downvote for ...brutish hackyness.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar with an export script. Here is the command I'm using:

```
cp -R demo_files/. demo
```

This will merge the files in demo_files with the files in demo. It shouldn't overwrite anything.

Comment: You *must* use -n option to indicate no overwrite of existing files in target directory.

Answer (score 0):

dirA
   dir1
      file1.txt
      file3.txt
dirB
   dir1
      file1.txt
      file2.txt

I would do it this way:

```
$ cd dirA
$ tar cf - | (cd .../dirB ; tar xf -)
```

Files get overwritten, directories don't.

Answer (score 0):

Erics solution worked but I had to tweak syntax a little:

```
$ cd dirA
$ tar -cf - ./* | (cd .../dirB ; tar -xf -)
```